# Jest Mock Dependency Injected classes

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I'm trying to unit test a class which is injected two other classes.

This is the class:

```
class StatementHandlerService {
    constructor( statementRepo, KafkaSQSHandler, statementArray ){
        //TODO: ADD NULLITY CHECKS
        if(statementRepo === undefined || statementRepo === null){
            throw new TypeError('StatementRepo must be defined');
        }
        if(KafkaSQSHandler === undefined || KafkaSQSHandler === null){
            throw new TypeError('SQSHandler must be defined');
        }
        if(statementArray === undefined || statementArray === null){
            throw new TypeError('Statement array must be defined');
        }
        this.statementRepository = statementRepo ;
        this.KafkaSQSHandler = KafkaSQSHandler;
        this.statements = statementArray;   
    }

    async storeAndSend()  {
        let taskArray = [];
        this.statements.forEach( s => {
            taskArray.push(this.KafkaSQSHandler.sendToKafkaSQS(s));
            taskArray.push(this.statementRepository.saveStatement(s));
        });

        return await Promise.all(taskArray);
    }
}

export default StatementHandlerService;
```

This is my test file:

```
jest.mock('./../Services/SQSKafkaHandler'); //Auto-mock the modules
jest.mock('./../Repository/StatementRepository');

import StatementRepository, {mockSaveStatement} from "../Repository/StatementRepository";
import SQSKafkaHandler, {mockSendToKafkaSQS} from "../Services/SQSKafkaHandler";

import StatementHandlerService from "../Services/StatementHandlerService";
import {expect, jest, test} from '@jest/globals';

describe('StatementHandlerService', () => {
    
    it('We can check if the consumer called the class constructor', () => {
        const sqs = new SQSKafkaHandler(); //Auto-mocked instances .
        const repo = new StatementRepository();
        const serviceUnderTest = new StatementHandlerService(sqs, repo, ['stmnt1', 'stmnt2']);
        expect(SQSKafkaHandler).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
    it('should work', async () => {
        const mockMethod = jest.fn( (s) => []);
        SQSKafkaHandler.mockImplementation( () => {
            return {
                sendToKafkaSQS: mockMethod,
            };
        });
        StatementRepository.mockImplementation( () => {
            return {
                saveStatement: mockMethod,
            };
        })
        const sqs = new SQSKafkaHandler(); //Auto-mocked instances .
        const repo = new StatementRepository();
        
        const serviceUnderTest = new StatementHandlerService(sqs, repo, ['stmnt1', 'stmnt2']);
        await serviceUnderTest.storeAndSend();

    });
    
});
```

However when I call the .storeAndSend() function I get an error:

```
    TypeError: this.KafkaSQSHandler.sendToKafkaSQS is not a function

      19 |         let taskArray = [];
      20 |         this.statements.forEach( s => {
    > 21 |             taskArray.push(this.KafkaSQSHandler.sendToKafkaSQS(s));
         |                                                 ^
      22 |             taskArray.push(this.statementRepository.saveStatement(s));
      23 |         });
```

I'd expect the `sendToKafkaSQS` function that I defined under mockImplementation is defined but it looks like it isn't.

I also tried creating the files `__mocks__/StatementRepository.js` but I get the same result.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor parameters of the `StatementHandlerService` class are `statementRepo`, `KafkaSQSHandler`, and `statementArray`.You didn't pass the parameters correctly.

It should be:

```js
const serviceUnderTest = new StatementHandlerService(repo, sqs, ['stmnt1', 'stmnt2']);
```

not:

```js
const serviceUnderTest = new StatementHandlerService(sqs, repo, ['stmnt1', 'stmnt2']);
```

Besides, if you mock the implementation of the `StatementRepository` and `SQSKafkaHandler` classes in test cases, you don't need `__mocks__` directory.

Comment: Damn, I should've gone to bed earlier. It's working Lin!